# ImageButton animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am implementing a animated book in Android and the animations are defined by an XML (not an Android XML). The images are positioned in fixed positions and when user touches in a element on the screen, the app plays a sound and animate the imagebutton, changing the image src and positions (X and Y).

I want to know how can I do that. As images dot not have the same size, I think the [sprites solution](http://obviam.net/index.php/sprite-animation-with-android/) is not a good way to solve it.

Its like the image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eCty.png):

Thank you

[image: example animation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of animations:

View Animation and Proprety Animation.

The view animation can only animate View objects. It also lack a variety of animations, since it can do only stuff as scale, rotate, move... It cannot change background color, for example. Also, the dissadvantage of the View Animation is that it only change the position of where the View object is DRAWN. Phisically, it still stays in the same position. That's why the button is unclickable, after the View Animation is finished upon it.

Property Animation, in the other hand, can animate both View and non-View objects and it doesn't have constraints as the View Animation. When objects are moved, for example, with the property animation, they are not just drawn on some other position on the screen, but they are actually MOVED there.

Now, Property Animation is a lot more complex to write than the View Animation, so if you don't really need all the advantages of the Property Animation, it is suggested to use View Animation.

Source: [Property vs ViewAnimation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

Tutorial and SupportLybrary up to API 1: [Nine Old Androids](http://nineoldandroids.com/)

Comment: So,if I have an item and this should de clicked again, I must use property animation, right?

Comment: That is correct. If you want your button to be clickable, after an animation is done, you should use property animation :)